# What does this pattern match when filtering strings for URLs

Tags: magento2, url, url-key, regex

What exactly is this line for

```
preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', parent::filter($string))
```

in the following method in [\vendor\magento\framework\Filter\TranslitUrl.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Filter/TranslitUrl.php#L21):

```
public function filter($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', parent::filter($string));
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = trim($string, '-');

    return $string;
}
```

The method is used to filter strings which will be used in URLs, and I know that line replaces some strings with `-` character. But I don't fully understand what exactly this pattern `#[^0-9a-z]+#i` matches.

I will appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern `#[^0-9a-z]+#i` matches all **NOT** numeric and **NOT** alphabetical symbols, in other words it will replace any symbol which is **NOT** in range *0-9* or *a-z* with the `-` symbol.

The `^` symbol inside group means it is negation (inversion).
The `#` symbols detects the start and end of the pattern.
The `i` flag says that *regular expression* should be case insensitive.

In the example string you can see a *blue* symbols, which will be replaced by that code with the `-` symbol:

[image: example]

So a result will be looking like this:

> my-mom-says-i-don-t-know-where-it-is

**The main purpose of this code is make string a valid URL-string**,  because you can insert inside the URL-key field whatever you want  in any language.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that the hash signs (#) can be delimiters of the regex pattern. So the pattern `#[^0-9a-z]+#i` is equivalent to `/[^0-9a-z]+/i`. Now all is clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `#[^0-9a-z]+#i`
 `0-9` -> which indicates numeric values.
 `a-z` -> which indicated small alphabetical values.
 `+#`  -> will allow `#` in url string.

Over all this pattern allow `numeric|alphabets|#` type patterns allows.